# Portable replacement for ECMAScript 6 Set?

Tags: javascript

I've written some code that uses ECMAScript 6 `Set`s in various recursive functions, to keep track of objects that have already been encountered (thereby avoiding infinite recursion); e.g.

```
function traverse(start, callback, next) {
    var seen = new Set();
    function _traverse(obj) {
        if (seen.has(obj)) { return }
        seen.add(obj);
        callback(obj);
        _traverse(next(obj));
    }
    return _traverse(start);
}
```

I prefer to use these `Set`s for this purpose over plain `Object`s, because the former distinguish between, e.g., between the integer `0` and the string `"0"`.

It is my understanding, however, that browser support for such `Set`s may not yet be widespread enough for production code.  Therefore, I'm looking for a more portable replacement with equal functionality (such as, e.g., distinguishing `0` and `"0"`, as described above).

Comment: See if this helps https://github.com/WebReflection/es6-collections

Comment: More general: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#ecmascript-6-harmony

Answer (score 1):

off the top of my head, this can be accomplished with an object and a bit of code.

an object is a `hash` and thus gives you 80% of the functionality you want. the problem with js objects is that their keys are always strings. This is where you write a bit of code.

I would create 2 objects:

one where your keys are strings and one where your keys start out as numbers but become strings. if thing thing you are inserting is number, check in the numbers object, if string, check in the other object.

psudocode:

```
numObj = {}
strObj = {}

add = (val) ->
  if _.isNumber(val)
    numObj[val] = true
  else
    strObj[val] = true

contains = (val) ->
  if _.isNumber(val)
    return !!numObj[val]
  else
    return !!strObj[val]
```